# Add an image tag to Jinja Template k from a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to create an image tag for a Jinja template with a variable from Ajax.

```
success: function (response) {
               var pythonResponse = "<ul id='userList'>";
               $.each(response,function(index,value) {
                    console.log(`path is ${value[0]}`)
                    pythonResponse += `<li onClick = 'selectUser("${value[1]}")'> ${value[1]}`
                    pythonResponse += `<img src={{ url_for('static', filename='${value[0])}')}}/></li>`
                    console.log(pythonResponse);
               });
```

The line in question is this one

```
pythonResponse += `<img src={{ url_for('static', filename='${value[0])}')}}/></li>`
```

When I run this code the variable `value[0]` which contains the file path, is rendered out as a bunch of gobbledygook. This is what it looks like `%24%7Bvalue%5B0%5D%29%7D/` but it should look like this `/myfolder/myFile.jpg`. I have confirmed that the variable does indeed equal what it is suposed to equal and if i hard code the file path into the `filename=''` then it works.
Why is this variable turned from this `/myfolder/myFile.jpg` into this `%24%7Bvalue%5B0%5D%29%7D/`?

Answer (score 0):

The order of application here is somewhat confusing.  If I'm understanding correctly that the javascript is being applied first, then the answer below should help.

Jinja is escaping your variable for safety.  It's possible to introduce security problems in your applications by using a variable the way you are using it here.  For information lookup XSS (cross site scripting) attacks for more information.

If you're sure the variable is safe, then Jinja allows you to avoid this encoding with the `safe` filter.

`` pythonResponse += `<img src={{ url_for('static', filename='${value[0])}') | safe}}/></li>` ``

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#safe

Comment: It still does that same thing. I have

Comment: i think that | safe does not work because its in quotations

Comment: i tried `let path = value[0]|safe;`  and i get an error saying that `Uncaught ReferenceError: safe is not defined`

Comment: This is what I meant about the order of application being difficult to follow here.  You're mixing Javascript and Jynja templating in a single line.  `safe` is a filter provided by Jynja, which is why JavaScript is throwing a reference error.  `{{ url_for('static', filename='${value[0])}')}}` the `{{}}` pair tell Jynja to interpret the line, which gives you access to the `url_for` function.  `${}` tells Javascript to interpret the inner value.  So the first important question is: does Jynja interpret first, or does Javascript?

Comment: javascript interprets first. Ajax sends info to python then python responds and im trying to make this image tag from the response and then send it to jinja. javascript interprets it first